# hl-line face used as default in 26.1

Tags: faces, hl-line-mode

When I use emacs 24.3.1 and run

```
/usr/bin/emacs -Q
```

Then <kbd>M-<</kbd> followed by <kbd>M-x</kbd>`global-hl-line-mode` and <kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-face`, emacs asks me

```
Describe face (default `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face'):
```

But when I use 26.1 and run

```
/usr/local/bin/emacs -Q
```

and run exactly the same commands, emacs asks me

```
Describe face (default ‘hl-line’):
```

I have to turn `hl-line` off to get the name of the point's face. What causes this difference and is there a way to get the old behaviour back?

*Update:*

It seems

```
(get-char-property (point) 'face)
```

returns `hl-line` in 26.1, but returns the actual face in 24.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that `describe-face` ultimately calls `get-char-property`
(via `face-at-point`). `get-char-property`, unlike its cousin
`get-text-property`, doesn't return just text properties, but also overlay
properties. And that's how `hl-line-mode` works: By setting the face
property on an overlay.

A cursory glance at Emacs' git repository at savannah.gnu.org, doesn't tell
me when and why there was some change. Anyways, you could argue that
interactive functions like `M-x describe-char` should special case
`hl-line-mode`. (Or: That might lead to confusion, so maybe not.) Be that as it may be, a possible temporary fix could be to
use advice:

```
(defun my-face-at-point ()
  (let ((face (get-text-property (point) 'face)))
    (or (and (face-list-p face)
             (car face))
        (and (symbolp face)
             face))))

(defun my-describe-face (&rest ignore)
  (interactive (list (read-face-name "Describe face"
                                     (or (my-face-at-point) 'default)
                                     t)))
  ;; This only needs to change the `interactive` spec, so:
  nil)

(eval-after-load "hl-line"
  '(advice-add 'describe-face :before #'my-describe-face))
```

You'd have to do that for every interactive function that is affected by
this, though, e.g. `M-x customize-face`, too.

Answer (score 1):

At the particular location of interest in the current buffer, type `C-u C-x =` and that will pull up a `*Help*` buffer that describes the various faces, text properties, overlays and additional information ...  There may be many things happening, and something may be trumping/superseding something else.

As to the default face that is proposed by `describe-face` if the user were to just press enter without actually inputting any particular face, or as to the difference between various versions of Emacs, I will leave that to another forum participant to create an alternative answer.